Moving from Apache to Nginx, problem with iFrame
I am moving a website from Apache to Nginx.
The page that contains an iframe https://wpdemo.hotjoomlatemplates.com/ won't load the iframe on Nginx because of "mixed content". This is not true, because the iframe src is set to HTTPS.
Also, the very same web page works fine without the "mixed content" error when I switch to another VPS that's based on Apache.
If you look at the page's source code, there's no one HTTP reference in it.
This is my Nginx configuration:
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 quic;
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 quic;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  http2 on;
  http3 off;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name wpdemo.hotjoomlatemplates.com;
  {{root}}

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  {{settings}}

  location / {
    {{varnish_proxy_pass}}
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout      720;
    proxy_send_timeout         720;
    proxy_read_timeout         720;
    proxy_buffer_size          128k;
    proxy_buffers              4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
  }

  location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf|map|mjs)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    add_header alt-svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400';
    add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOWALL";
    expires max;
    access_log off;
  }

  location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
    deny all;
  }

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}

server {
  listen 8080;
  listen [::]:8080;
  server_name wpdemo.hotjoomlatemplates.com;
  {{root}}

  include /etc/nginx/global_settings;

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  index index.php index.html;
  
  autoindex off;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 443;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:{{php_fpm_port}};
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "{{php_settings}}";
  }

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}

Thanks,
Milos

I found out that I need to add a strict content security policy in the nginx.conf to enforce HTTPS:
add_header Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests";

